# Passport Send Mail Strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am creating a NodeJS app which requires that the user registers; I'm using passport to manage the autentication ('local' strategy) but now i need to modify the strategy. I need that, first the user registers, then a mail is send to one (or more) administrators with a Link to aprove or not the registration. I remember that in Moodle it is something called "email-based self-registration".

I know i can do this manually, but I suppose that passport or other library has this functionality implemented. ¿someone knows if it is possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Passport only does user authentication.

Take a look at Drywall, which uses Express and Passport. http://jedireza.github.io/drywall/